# Subtracting values in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello I am running the query below and I am getting a null value for my [sumofnetsales] amount. Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Also, if I was wanting to use [SumofAmountShipped] column instead of summing it again in the subtraction equation, how would I do that? Thank you.

```
DECLARE @Rundate datetime
SET @RunDate = '3/11/2013' -- Date they run the report 


--Temp Tables to sum up all accural types

Declare @Chargeback table (Amount money, ShortItemNo int, ProductName varchar(50))
INSERT @Chargeback
SELECT sum(a.AccrualAmount),
       ShortItemNo,
       ProductName
FROM 
    Accruals a
WHERE 
    @RunDate between a.AccrualBeginDate and a.AccrualEndDate and a.enddate = '12/31/2200' and accrualtype = 2
Group By
    ShortItemNo,
    ProductName


Declare @AdjustedForNetPrice table (Amount money, ShortItemNo int, ProductName varchar(50))
INSERT @AdjustedForNetPrice
SELECT sum(a.AccrualAmount),
       ShortItemNo,
       ProductName
FROM 
    Accruals a
WHERE 
    @RunDate between a.AccrualBeginDate and a.AccrualEndDate and a.enddate = '12/31/2200' and accrualtype = 2
Group By
    ShortItemNo,
    ProductName


Declare @AdminFee table (Amount money, ShortItemNo int, ProductName varchar(50))
INSERT @AdminFee
SELECT sum(a.AccrualAmount),
       ShortItemNo,
       ProductName
FROM 
    Accruals a
WHERE 
    @RunDate between a.AccrualBeginDate and a.AccrualEndDate and a.enddate = '12/31/2200' and accrualtype = 1
Group By
    ShortItemNo,
    ProductName


Declare @Returns table (Amount money, ShortItemNo int, ProductName varchar(50))
INSERT @Returns
SELECT sum(a.AccrualAmount),
       ShortItemNo,
       ProductName
FROM 
    Accruals a
WHERE 
    @RunDate between a.AccrualBeginDate and a.AccrualEndDate and a.enddate = '12/31/2200' and accrualtype = 3
Group By
    ShortItemNo,
    ProductName


Declare @Rebates table (Amount money, ShortItemNo int, ProductName varchar(50))
INSERT @Rebates
SELECT sum(a.AccrualAmount),
       ShortItemNo,
       ProductName
FROM 
    Accruals a
WHERE 
    @RunDate between a.AccrualBeginDate and a.AccrualEndDate and a.enddate = '12/31/2200' and accrualtype = 4
Group By
    ShortItemNo,
    ProductName


Declare @ACCPSW1 table (Amount money, ShortItemNo int, ProductName varchar(50))
INSERT @ACCPSW1
SELECT sum(a.AccrualAmount),
       ShortItemNo,
       ProductName
FROM 
    Accruals a
WHERE 
    @RunDate between a.AccrualBeginDate and a.AccrualEndDate and a.enddate = '12/31/2200' and accrualtype = 5
Group By
    ShortItemNo,
    ProductName


Declare @CashDiscount table (Amount money, ShortItemNo int, ProductName varchar(50))
INSERT @CashDiscount
SELECT sum(a.AccrualAmount),
       ShortItemNo,
       ProductName
FROM 
    Accruals a
WHERE 
    @RunDate between a.AccrualBeginDate and a.AccrualEndDate and a.enddate = '12/31/2200' and accrualtype = 6
Group By
    ShortItemNo,
    ProductName


Declare @INIT1 table (Amount money, ShortItemNo int, ProductName varchar(50))
INSERT @INIT1 
SELECT sum(a.AccrualAmount),
       ShortItemNo,
       ProductName
FROM 
    Accruals a
WHERE 
    @RunDate between a.AccrualBeginDate and a.AccrualEndDate and a.enddate = '12/31/2200' and accrualtype = 7
Group By
    ShortItemNo,
    ProductName


Declare @Medicaid table (Amount money, ShortItemNo int, ProductName varchar(50))
INSERT @Medicaid 
SELECT sum(a.AccrualAmount),
       ShortItemNo,
       ProductName
FROM 
    Accruals a
WHERE 
    @RunDate between a.AccrualBeginDate and a.AccrualEndDate and a.enddate = '12/31/2200' and accrualtype = 8
Group By
    ShortItemNo,
    ProductName


Declare @InitialOrderDiscount table (Amount money, ShortItemNo int, ProductName varchar(50))
INSERT @InitialOrderDiscount
SELECT sum(a.AccrualAmount),
       ShortItemNo,
       ProductName
FROM 
    Accruals a
WHERE 
    @RunDate between a.AccrualBeginDate and a.AccrualEndDate and a.enddate = '12/31/2200' and accrualtype = 9
Group By
    ShortItemNo,
    ProductName





SELECT
    rtrim(IMDSC1) [ItemDesc1],
    rtrim(IMDSC2) [ItemDesc2],
    sum(QuantityShipped) [SumOfQuantityShipped],
    sum(ExtendedPrice) [SumOfAmountShipped],
    rtrim(IMSRTX) [BrandName],
    '' [SumOfNetSaleUnitPrice],
    sum(ExtendedPrice) - c.Amount - a.Amount - af.Amount - r.Amount - rr.Amount - ac.Amount - cd.Amount - i.Amount - m.Amount - id.Amount [SumOfNetSales],
    '' [SumOfGrossProfit],
    '' [SumOfGrossMargin],
    '3/11/2013' [Rundate]
FROM
    SalesSummary ss join [Product] p 
        on ss.ShortItemNo = p.SDITM
    join JDE_PRODUCTION.PRODDTA.F4101 im 
        on im.IMITM = p.SDITM
    left join @Chargeback c 
        on c.ShortItemNo = ss.ShortItemNo
    left join @AdjustedForNetPrice a
        on a.ShortItemNo = ss.ShortItemNo
    left join @AdminFee af
        on af.ShortItemNo = ss.ShortItemNo
    left join @Returns r 
        on r.ShortItemNo = ss.ShortItemNo
    join @Rebates rr
        on rr.ShortItemNo = ss.ShortItemNo
    left join @ACCPSW1 ac
        on ac.ShortItemNo = ss.ShortItemNo
    left join @CashDiscount cd
        on cd.ShortItemNo = ss.ShortItemNo
    left join @INIT1 i
        on i.ShortItemNo = ss.ShortItemNo
    left join @Medicaid m
        on m.ShortItemNo = ss.ShortItemNo
    left join @InitialOrderDiscount id
        on id.ShortItemNo = ss.ShortItemNo      

WHERE 
    ss.InvoiceDate = @RunDate

GROUP BY
    rtrim(IMDSC1),
    rtrim(IMDSC2),
    rtrim(IMSRTX),
    c.Amount,
    a.Amount,
    af.Amount,
    r.Amount,
    rr.Amount,
    ac.Amount,
    cd.Amount,
    i.Amount,
    m.Amount,
    id.Amount
ORDER BY 
    rtrim(IMDSC1),
    rtrim(IMDSC2)
```

Comment: There is a lot of SQL code in your example. Are you able to simplify the example down (can you recreate the same problem with fewer temp tables)? Doing so might also help you unpick the problem by yourself.

Comment: You can just focus on the select query. The temp tables are basically repeating.

Comment: One of various `amount` columns is null probably due to one or more of `left join`s. You migh wrap each column in [isnull](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)(column, 0) to avoid null results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting `null` because one of the column values in the subtraction is `null`. It's like:

```
1000 - null = null
```

You have to use `coalesce(<column>, 0)` (= the ANSI SQL way) to avoid this, or the `ISNULL()` function (SQL Server specific). Your subtraction line would look like:

```
sum(coalesce(ExtendedPrice, 0)) - coalesce(c.Amount,0) - coalesce(a.Amount, 0) 
    - coalesce(af.Amount, 0) - ... and so on ... [SumOfNetSales]
```

As of your second point: you can't avoid writing out the [SumofAmountShipped] column in the subtraction, because you can't use a just defined alias in the same statement.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly difficult to understand your code but the problem most likely lies with the JOIN.

When using a left join, if only the left side exists it will return the left side + NULLs on the right side.
If you do any arithmetic where a NULL is involved, the outcome will always be NULL.

To get around this use the `ISNULL` function to return 0 instead of the NULL for each value in the subtraction.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting Null value for [sumofnetsales] because you are not having a matching value in table @InitialOrderDiscount(**left join @InitialOrderDiscount id on id.ShortItemNo = ss.ShortItemNo**). So to avoid NULL you can have your column like:

```
ISNULL(id.Amount,0)[SumOfNetSales]
```